# TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters trying to subclass torch.FloatTensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, pytorch

I'm trying to subclass `torch.FloatTensor` in Python 3 and am having trouble calling the superclass `__init__`. Minimal example:

```
import inspect
import torch

x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

print(torch.FloatTensor(x))
'''
 1  2
 3  4
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2]
'''

print(inspect.signature(torch.FloatTensor.__init__))
'''
(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
'''

class Image(torch.FloatTensor):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print(inspect.signature(super().__init__))
        super().__init__(arg)

Image(x)
'''
(*args, **kwargs)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-369-4b1aee6414f6> in <module>()
     21         super().__init__(arg)
     22 
---> 23 Image(x)

<ipython-input-369-4b1aee6414f6> in __init__(self, arg)
     19     def __init__(self, arg):
     20         print(inspect.signature(super().__init__))
---> 21         super().__init__(arg)
     22 
     23 Image(x)

TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
'''
```

I'm relatively new to Python so I might be missing something obvious. Why does it say `object.__init__() takes no parameters` when inspecting shows it can take `(*args, **kwargs)`?

Edit: `torch.FloatTensor` is defined [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/__init__.py). It is derived from `torch._TensorBase` which is defined [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/tensor.py).

Comment: Try changing your initializer to `def __init__(self, *args):` and `super().__init__(*args)`. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tried that, no luck; it gives the same error. Same thing if I add `**kwargs` as well.

Comment: Maybe you could try calling it directly instead of using `super()`?  `torch.FloatTensor.__init__(self, arg)`? I don't think this should be the solution, but if this does work, then it might be a sign of a larger issue.

Comment: That also did not work, and the error message was the same.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. It seems as if it thinks `torch.FloatTensor` is an `object`. If you just looked at the output for `torch.FloatTensor`, is it shown as a class?

Comment: I added links to `torch.FloatTensor`'s definition in my edit. It seems that `torch.FloatTensor` and `torch._TensorBase` simply don't have `__init__` which would explain why my `super().__init__` bubbles up to `object`. But then, how does `torch.FloatTensor(x)` work?

Comment: The logic is probably in `__new__()` instead.  Maybe you'll have to define that instead.